# Subtract range of dates from each date in df column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df :

```
ID    date
1      05-01
2      04-08
3      06-08
4      03-07
...
```

and a date range from 01-01-2013 until 12-31-2013: `pd.date_range(start='1/1/2013', end='31/12/2013')`

I want for each date in the df, to get the **difference in days** between this date to each date in the date range. for example to get such df :

```
05-01  - 01-01       04-08  -  01-01  
05-01  - 01-02       04-08  -  01-02
05-01  - 01-03       04-08  -  01-03
..                    ..
05-01 -  12-31       04-08-12-31
```

and so on for each date..
Thanks

Comment: do you want the value of dates in between or just the string like this `05-01  - 01-01 `?

Comment: The value in days

Comment: The question, then, is which year are those dates from? The date range is 2013. are the column values as well?

Comment: yes all of the dates range is  2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to convert the `date` column to datetime. Then we can perform the subtraction.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'date': ['05-01', '04-08', '06-08', '03-07']
})
```

If `date` is in the format of `%d-%m` we can converting [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) by appending the year and set `dayfirst=True`. Then we can [`broadcast`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) subtraction and create a new dataframe from the results:

```
# append year and convert to datetime64[ns]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + '-2013', dayfirst=True)
# Build the date range
dr = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2013', end='31/12/2013')
# Create new DataFrame from the broadcasted subtraction.
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    df['date'].values - dr.values[:, None],
    columns=df['date'].rename(None),
    index=dr
)
```

`df`:

```
   ID       date
0   1 2013-01-05
1   2 2013-08-04
2   3 2013-08-06
3   4 2013-07-03
```

`new_df` (day first):

```
           2013-01-05 2013-08-04 2013-08-06 2013-07-03
2013-01-01     4 days   215 days   217 days   183 days
2013-01-02     3 days   214 days   216 days   182 days
2013-01-03     2 days   213 days   215 days   181 days
2013-01-04     1 days   212 days   214 days   180 days
2013-01-05     0 days   211 days   213 days   179 days
...               ...        ...        ...        ...
2013-12-27  -356 days  -145 days  -143 days  -177 days
2013-12-28  -357 days  -146 days  -144 days  -178 days
2013-12-29  -358 days  -147 days  -145 days  -179 days
2013-12-30  -359 days  -148 days  -146 days  -180 days
2013-12-31  -360 days  -149 days  -147 days  -181 days

[365 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

If `date` is in format `%m-%d` we can prepend the year. The subtraction is exactly the same:

```
# Prepend year and convert to datetime64[ns]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2013-' + df['date'])
# Build the date range
dr = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2013', end='31/12/2013')
# Create new DataFrame from the broadcasted subtraction.
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    df['date'].values - dr.values[:, None],
    columns=df['date'].rename(None),
    index=dr
)
```

`df`:

```
   ID       date
0   1 2013-05-01
1   2 2013-04-08
2   3 2013-06-08
3   4 2013-03-07
```

`new_df` (month first):

```
           2013-05-01 2013-04-08 2013-06-08 2013-03-07
2013-01-01   120 days    97 days   158 days    65 days
2013-01-02   119 days    96 days   157 days    64 days
2013-01-03   118 days    95 days   156 days    63 days
2013-01-04   117 days    94 days   155 days    62 days
2013-01-05   116 days    93 days   154 days    61 days
...               ...        ...        ...        ...
2013-12-27  -240 days  -263 days  -202 days  -295 days
2013-12-28  -241 days  -264 days  -203 days  -296 days
2013-12-29  -242 days  -265 days  -204 days  -297 days
2013-12-30  -243 days  -266 days  -205 days  -298 days
2013-12-31  -244 days  -267 days  -206 days  -299 days

[365 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

If just the day number is wanted we can divide by 1 day (floor division is safe as these are all dates with no time element so will only have whole number day time deltas):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    (df['date'].values - dr.values[:, None]) // pd.Timedelta('1D'),
    columns=df['date'].rename(None),
    index=dr
)
```

`new_df`:

```
            2013-01-05  2013-08-04  2013-08-06  2013-07-03
2013-01-01           4         215         217         183
2013-01-02           3         214         216         182
2013-01-03           2         213         215         181
2013-01-04           1         212         214         180
2013-01-05           0         211         213         179
...                ...         ...         ...         ...
2013-12-27        -356        -145        -143        -177
2013-12-28        -357        -146        -144        -178
2013-12-29        -358        -147        -145        -179
2013-12-30        -359        -148        -146        -180
2013-12-31        -360        -149        -147        -181
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]+"-2013", format="%m-%d-%Y")
dates = pd.date_range(start="1/1/2013", end="31/12/2013")
data = df["date"].apply(lambda x: [(x-dt).days for dt in dates]).tolist()

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=df["date"], columns=dates).transpose()

>>> new_df
date        2013-05-01  2013-04-08  2013-06-08  2013-03-07
2013-01-01         120          97         158          65
2013-01-02         119          96         157          64
2013-01-03         118          95         156          63
2013-01-04         117          94         155          62
2013-01-05         116          93         154          61
               ...         ...         ...         ...
2013-12-27        -240        -263        -202        -295
2013-12-28        -241        -264        -203        -296
2013-12-29        -242        -265        -204        -297
2013-12-30        -243        -266        -205        -298
2013-12-31        -244        -267        -206        -299
```

Each value in the DataFrame shows the difference in days between the column header and the row index.